# React и серверный рендеринг

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, ssr

Пишу проекты на React. Периодически требуется рендерить для ботов SPA на сервере. Но писать каждый раз с нуля на express SSR для реакта, это лично как по мне - боль и страдание.

Имеются ли готовые решения для моей задачи?

Comment: А так ли нужен в вашей задаче Реакт?

Comment: @PavelMayorov лично меня для моих задач устраивает реакт, не устраивает только боль с SSR. А вы хотели посоветовать что-то другое?

Comment: посмотри в сторону next js.  там есть встроенный ssr.